# An idenity related to Gamma function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I know that for [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) we have $$\int_0^{\infty}v^{k}e^{-av}dv=a^{-k-1}\Gamma(1+k),$$ given that $\Re(k)>-1$ and $\Re(a)>0$.

**Question**: Now considering $$\frac{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}v^{k}e^{-iav}dv}{y}=a^{-k-1}$$

can we choose $x_1,x_2$ and $y$ such that this identity holds, while $x_1,x_2$ and $y$ are free of $a$?

I appreciate your help and hints.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integral 
\begin{align}
I_{k} = \int x^{k} \, e^{-i a x} dx
\end{align}
for which integration by parts and forming the resulting expression into a power series yields
\begin{align}
I_{k} = \frac{ (-i)^{k-1} \, k!}{ a^{k+1} } \, e^{-i a x} \, e_{k}(-i a x)
\end{align}
where $e_{m}(x)$ is the finite exponential series given by
\begin{align}
e_{m}(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{m} \frac{x^{r}}{r!}.
\end{align}

The question is to determine limits and a normalizing factor such that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{y} \int_{\theta}^{\phi} x^{k} e^{-i a x} dx = \frac{1}{a^{k+1}}.
\end{align}
Values of $\phi$, $\theta$, and $y$ can be obtained from the above results. 
As an example for the case of $\theta = 0$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a^{k+1}} = \frac{e^{i a \phi}}{k! \, e_{k}(- i a \phi)} \int_{0}^{\phi} x^{k} \, e^{- i a x} dx.
\end{align}

Comment: This is nice, many thanks. Do you the this I could choose $\phi$ such that normalizing factor, i.e. $y$ does not involve $a$?